# Notation for "and"

Tags: notation

Consider the real numbers $a$ and $b$. I would like to express in math notation, that $c = 2$ if $a > 0$ **and** $b > 0$. Can I use the wedge symbol here like

$c = 2 \quad \text{ if }a>0 \wedge b>0$

or is this wrong usage of the wedge symbol? Is there a better way to express this?

Comment: you could write that

Comment: This is not a wrong usage of $\land$, but in that specific context, I'd prefer "and"

Comment: Overuse of logical symbols always make things harder to read (for no real reason).

Comment: I agree with @Randall. Better to write 'and'.

Comment: How you choose to write things like this depend largely on personal preference.  I would just as easily chosen to write $(a,b)\in\Bbb R_+^2 \implies c = 2$, having skipped the "and" and instead written $a,b$ as a tuple.

Comment: I like the wedge when dealing with formal logic because it makes computer-based resolution simpler.  But in your case I'd clarify with parentheses:  $c=2\ {\rm if}\ (a > 0 \wedge b > 0)$.  It occasionally depends upon circumstances, but my preferences would be:  $(\{a,b \} > 0) \rightarrow c = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on you. Anyway in my opinion "and" is more elegant choice in this case.